# Cannot call method 'use' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a problem with implementing passport in node.js express.

I am trying to follow different guides, but just won't succeed..

This time theres an error like this:

[image]

My code looks like this:

In app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Configuring Passport
var passport = require('passport');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
// TODO - Why Do we need this key ?
app.use(expressSession({secret: 'mySecretKey'}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Any idea why it wont work?
I have installed express-session, passport, passport-local etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to initialize `app` with `express()`

```
  var express= require('express');
    var app=express();
```

Comment: I did that already, but below the passport code. Moved it above and now it works! Thanks for that :)